# Is it normal (ok) to modify a collection (array, whatever) passed as parameter of a method?

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, parameter-passing

is it ok, normal, follows standard guidelines ... (you got it) to have a method like the following one:

```
public void Method(IList<int> test)
{
    test.Add(1);
}
```

Somehow I expected some information from the method signature that the parameter would be modified (like ref or out) or a convention like return the same list as the return value, something like:

```
public IList<int> Method(IList<int> test)
{
    test.Add(1);
    return test;
}
```

What do you think?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The method signature can provide this information implicitly: if you don't intend to modify the argument you should downgrade its type to a read-only type (in this case, `IEnumerable<int>`). In general it is preferable to have "pure" methods (without any side effects) but of course when you want to make an omelette you will have to break some eggs.

Comment: I personally try to avoid side effects like that in public methods unless it's extremely obvious that that's the intent.

Comment: @Jon, the problem is that you sometimes want an indexer, and .Net doesn't provide any read-only interfaces with an indexer (unfortunately).

Comment: @itsme86, IMO, if the method takes an `IList` parameter, it is loudly saying the method might modify the collection.  As Jon mentions, if you want to imply that the collection will *not* be modified, declare a parameter like `IEnumerable` that prevents it syntactically.

Comment: @Grzenio: `IReadOnlyList<T>`?

Comment: @Jon, .NET Framework 4.5. Will take years for my company to upgrade :( Thanks for letting me know though, this is definitely step in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally try to avoid these kind of methods, and try to stick to a more "functional" style where the method takes some inputs returns outputs. Of course, sometimes it makes most sense to actually change the list in the method, but then I am trying to be very explicit with the method name.

On a side note, your second example is the worst of both worlds: not only it modifies the parameter, but also hides this fact by having a return value. This one is definitely a code smell.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly OK in the C# and Java world.

This is one thing that's always made me a bit uneasy coming from a C++ background. In C++, as a library author, I can mark methods parameters as `const` to indicate that you--the client code--may safely give me your data and I--the library--promise to use it without disturbing it.

You're not going to get that in C# and Java. The philosophy is that you pass around references all over the place without making copies for efficiency, but in doing so, you're permitting the library to make changes to your data. Normally, this works out well because the library won't touch your data unless it's written in the class documentation; however, there's no compiler-enforced guarantee of this.

If you--the client code author--are truly paranoid about your data being modified when handing off to a library, the burden is on you to copy or clone your data before handing it off to my library. In doing so, you incur the run-time penalty of making the copy.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IList<int> Method(IList<int> test)
{
    test.Add(1);
    return test;
}
```

The type `IList<int>` actually already says you need `IList<T>` methods (such as `Add`) that are not present in `IEnumerable<T>`.

Of course, you'll need to document what the method actually does, by providing a useful name for the method as well as XML documentation if it's publicly available to other developers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if it is known with nice doc comments for the developer or the process makes it know with a nice descriptive method name. Using the name `Method(List)` is not.

```
public void FindMoreIds(IList<int> ids)
{
     ...
     ids.Add(...);
     ...
}
```

Now this works because it kind of makes sense that the collection will be modified looking at the signature. What you do **not** want to do is set something up like this:

```
public IList<int> FindMoreIds(IList<int> ids)
{
     ...
     ids.Add(...);
     ...
     return ids;
}
```

A developer would think that the original collection they passed would be unmodified.

There are of course other solutions to use if you don't plan on modifying the collection. You could use `IEnumerable<T>` or an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if your functional somewhere in code connected with index operations (for arrays especially) you could reach out of range exception